# SQL Query Flattens Order and Top Order Items

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help building a SQL query that returns a flattened result of the top 2 items in an order.

The tables and relevant fields are as follows:

```
Order        OrderItem       
-------      -----------     
orderId      orderId         
             productCode     
             quantity
```

I'm looking for the desired result set:

```
[orderId]    [productCode1]    [quantity1]    [productCode2]    [quantity2]
----------   --------------    -----------    --------------    -----------
o123         p134              3              p947              1   
o456         p384              2              p576              1
```

The results would be grouped by `orderId` from `Order`, with the TOP 2 `productCode` from `quantity` from `OrderItem`. I don't care which TOP 2 get returned, just need any two.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: which version of SQL-Server are you using?

Comment: can you show some example data please?

Comment: Can the same productcode appear on multiple OrderItem records for a single order? (in other words - what is the PK of the OrderItem Table)

Comment: The PK of OrderItem is orderItemID, the productCode is not unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    o.orderId,
    max(case when row_num = 1 then oi.ProductCode end) as ProductCode1,
    max(case when row_num = 1 then oi.Quantity end) as Quantity1,
    max(case when row_num = 2 then oi.ProductCode end) as ProductCode2,
    max(case when row_num = 2 then oi.Quantity end) as Quantity2
from Order as o
   outer apply (
       select top 2
           oi.*, row_number() over (order by oi.productCode) as row_num
       from OrderItem as oi
       where oi.orderId = o.orderId
   ) as oi
group by o.orderId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with conditional aggregation and the window function `row_number()`:

```
select orderId,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then ProductCode end) as ProductCode1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then Quantity end) as Quantity1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then ProductCode end) as ProductCode2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then Quantity end) as Quantity2
from (select oi.*,
             row_number() over (partition by orderId order by quantity desc) as seqnum
      from OrderItem oi
     ) oi
group by orderId;
```

Comment: the last case has a typo, it says 12 instead of 2.

Comment: I added 'as oi' after 'from OrderItem', but get the error message 'syntax error near orderId'

Comment: @ClayDavis . . . What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: MSSQL, not sure of the version

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `SQL Server 2005` or later you can create a CTE ordered by `ProductCode`, then in a second CTE take the rows with rank 2 and last `join` them to `Orders`

```
;WITH OrderItem1 AS 
(
    SELECT OrderID, productCode AS productCode1, quantity AS quantity1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION  BY OrderID ORDER BY productCode) AS RowID
    FROM [OrderItem] 
), 
OrderItem2 AS 
(
    SELECT OrderID, productCode1 AS productCode2, quantity1 AS quantity2
    FROM [OrderItem1] 
    WHERE RowID = 2
)
SELECT [Order].OrderID, [OrderItem1].[productCode1], [OrderItem1].quantity1,
       [OrderItem2].productCode2, [OrderItem2].quantity2
FROM [Order]
INNER JOIN OrderItem1 ON [Order].OrderID = OrderItem1.OrderID
LEFT JOIN OrderItem2 ON [Order].OrderID = OrderItem2.OrderID
WHERE OrderItem1.RowID = 1
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error with the WITH on this one. I'm using MSSQL.

Comment: As stated above, this query works with `SQL Server 2005` or later. Yesterday I asked , what version of `SQL Server` are you using?

Comment: I'm using a hosted ecommerce solution. I talked to support and the first line person only knew that they were using MSSQL, didn't know the version.